# Definir propiedades de la Instancia mediante variables en Javascript

Tags: html5, api, javascript-objeto

**Hola, a todos.**
Estoy tratando de consumir a una **API** de una pasarela de Pagos, desde un Boton de pago, en la documentación de ellos me enseñan como hacerlo y funciona correctamente, sin embargo en el ejemplo lo hacen con valores predefinidos, y yo necesito que **2** campos **amountInCents** y **reference**, se llenen dinamicamente por decirlo así.

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta el momento,
por motivos de seguridad no puedo mostrarles mi **publicKey**, sin embargo, espero que puedan se amables y me ayuden

```html
<head>
    <!-- Uuid -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uuid@latest/dist/umd/uuidv4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Wompi Styles-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkout.wompi.co/widget.js"></script>
</head>         

<body>
    <button class="btn btn-success w-5" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" onclick="pagar_wompi()">Paga con Wompi</button>

    <form>
        <input type='number' id="price"></input>

        <script>
            var reference1 = uuid.v4();
            amountInCents1 = document.getElementById(price);

            var checkout = new WidgetCheckout({
            currency: 'COP',
            amountInCents= amountInCents1,
            reference= reference1,
            publicKey: 'pub_test_2Jb52G0AYuaY8CW4Tf3Gt8ksLgRQWddu',
            redirectUrl: 'https://transaction-redirect.wompi.co/check' // Opcional
            })

            function pagar_wompi() {
             checkout.open(function ( result ) {
             var transaction = result.transaction
             })
            }
       </script>
  </form>
</body>
```

El campo **amountInCents** es el valor que el cliente deberá pagar, necesito llenarlo mediante la digitación en una caja de **texto input**.

y el campo **reference**, es el numero de factura, lo estoy creando con una libreria que se llama **uuidv4** para crear numeros unicos.

espero puedas colaborarme pronto, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar las variables en el momento, como tal no son variables de ambiente, si no que cuando tu declaras una variable esta vive en el **scope** en el que fue declarada, en este caso si colocas las variables dentro del scope de la función estas serán completamente nuevas, por lo que siempre que ejecutes la funcion pagar_wompi se volveran a leer/generar los valores de reference y amountInCents:

```
function pagar_wompi() {
  var reference = uuid.v4();
  var amountInCents = document.getElementById(price);

  new WidgetCheckout({
    currency: 'COP',
    amountInCents: amountInCents,
    reference: reference,
    publicKey: 'pub_test_2Jb52G0AYuaY8CW4Tf3Gt8ksLgRQWddu',
    redirectUrl: 'https://transaction-redirect.wompi.co/check' // Opcional
  }).open(function(result) {
    var transaction = result.transaction
  })
}
```

Documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var

Comment: Aségurate de no tener errores de sintaxis... Se te han colado un par de `=` que deberían ser `:`. Adicionalmente, puedes obviar el nombre de la *key* si tu variable tiene el mismo nombre.

Comment: Muchas gracias **Daniel Norris** por tu pronta respuesta, estuve probando con la solución que me planteaste, sin embargo no ha podido funcionar, al parecer si omito la variable  `checkout` me sale que `pagar_wompi()` no esta definido.

Comment: **VRoxa**, tienes razón, tengo algunos errores en la sintaxis, esto es debido a que conozco muy poco `Javascript ` soy muy nuevo en este lenguaje, Muchas gracias por tu comentario

Comment: Cierto, corregí los errores de sintaxis